# Android - GoogleMaps - display markers without internet connection?

Tags: android, google-maps

lately my client wants to add functionality like that:
when user have Internet connection maps are displayed normaly, but when user starts app offline(even just after instalation), maps arent shown but he can still see markers on its area however with custom background on it?

I see some way to add overlay for background but if theres a way to show markers?
I have never met with something like that, and after searching app I'm not 100% sure is there anything like that possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It might be possible when you detect before that you don't have internet connection and display some kind of 'prepared bitmap' where you put correctly your saved markers.

Comment: What about eg. zooming? I want to preserve all functionalities if possible.

Comment: Bitmap can be zoomed if you provide that functionality in the same way as on googles map. I think that you have to simply mock google map and provide your own implementation of it based on one picture.

Comment: @Rafik991 bitmap is a way but not when my app alows to add markers dynamicaly in few places, so markers location,images,etc can change at runtime, so way You suggest is a little overkill IMHO. Besides I'm more interested in how to achive that using API, not just by myself(don't take that as if I'm lazy, in my case time is the most important factor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Maps Android API v2 needs to connect to server to confirm your API key is correct. It won't display any data (including markers) before that.

After the first connection, the result is stored and you don't need internet to display markers. The map data won't load obviously (unless it is cached), but markers will appear.

I consider it a bug that you cannot display markers (or other visual objects like polylines) without checking API key correctness. It would make more sense to force that only when you want to load Google map tiles. It was actually requested on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5496).

Comment: Thanks for the info,  thats what I've searched for!

Comment: Thanks for valuable info! But how can we know when Map could work (after confirming API key). Is there a callback?

Comment: @khigianguyen I think it's why [`OnMapLoadedCallback`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback) is there.